# Display a spinner's adapter from code

Tags: android, spinner

I have two spinners. When an item is selected from spinner1, I want spinner2's list to come up so I can select an item from that one immediately afterwards, without having to manually click on spinner2. Is there a method to call this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in spinner 1's onitemclicklistener try doing a performClick() on spinner 2

Comment: As a follow up, note that the second spinner must have it's OnClickListener defined as per the API. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#performClick()